# 90 day SOFR market rate to equivalent 3M Libor rate conversion

Tags: forward-rate, libor

I am trying to convert a 90 day SOFR market rate into a fair equivalent 3 month Libor rate. I understand since SOFR is by nature an in-arrears backwards looking rate, so for SOFR instruments such as a 90 day SOFR swap we need to wait until the end of the accrual period to know the fixing value.

I'm trying to use the Generalized Forward market model [from this paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3330240). Section 2.5 mentions how the two rates can be consolidated. I believe the equation that does so is equation 20 on page 9 :Drift(Rj
; Q)(t) − Drift(Rj
; Q
d
)(t) = τη(t)ση(t)(t)gη(t)(t)
1 + τη(t)Rη(t)(t)
σj (t)gj (t)ρη(t),j

Is the key to converting between a 90 day SOFR market rate and a 3 month Libor date in determining the SOFR forward, and then confirming this as the Libor forward by the principal of no arbitrage? If I am completely wrong, would anyone be able to suggest a better conversion formula or methodology? Thank you for your guidance